# PostgreSQL: what does pg_xact_commit_timestamp() return if the xid was from a failed transaction?

Tags: postgresql, transactions

For example, suppose `xid 6834` is rollback, then what should this return?

```
select pg_xact_commit_timestamp('6834'::xid);
```

There is nothing mentioned in the doc ... it seems assumed the xid is from a committed transaction. So my question is the answer stable and meaningful for such rollback transactions?  can get such xid via, e.g., `select txid_current();` from within a `BEGIN ... ROLLBACK` uow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will return `NULL`:

```
test=> BEGIN;
BEGIN
test=> SELECT txid_current();
 txid_current
--------------
         1942
(1 row)

test=> ROLLBACK;
ROLLBACK
test=> select pg_xact_commit_timestamp('1942'::xid) IS NULL;
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```